# UE 5.1: Everything works, then you restart the engine, nothing works

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

Working on a client project. Got so much stuff done. Everything works great. Created a build, it works perfectly.

Then I shut down my laptop, the next day I boot it up and everything is broken.

**zero** changes were made to the project.

This is the **second** time this happens. Like what the heck?!

Has this happened to anyone else? This is so infuriating..

I can't event figure out what is happening, I can't detect what changed.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate Live Coding.

Ctrl+Alt+P to compile from unreal, sometimes crash, save before it.

U can use Ctrl+F5 from Visual Studio to Build and open Unreal project.

Greetings!